# How to prevent full match and only match groups

Tags: regex, vba

I would like to know how you stop a full match with a regex.

With a pattern of:

`===(.+)[\r\n](.+)`

and an input of:

`===Index Plate
20137-001.zoe
===Digi Erox
20137-001A.zoe`

Produces:

`Full match: ===Index Plate
             20137-001.zoe`

`Group 1: ===Index Plate`

`Group 2: 20137-001.zoe`

`Full match: ===Digi Erox
            20137-001A.zoe`

`Group 1: ===Digi Erox`

`Group 2: 20137-001A.zoe`

But, I could really do without the full match and just match the group 1 and group 2.

i.e. I just need this:

`Group 1: ===Index Plate`

`Group 2: 20137-001.zoe`

`Group 1: ===Digi Erox`

`Group 2: 20137-001A.zoe`

How do you do that with a regex?

Comment: I am not sure if you can get rid of the full match, but if you also want `Group 1: ===Index Plate` then you could  move the triple times = into the capturing group `(===.+)[\r\n](.+)`

Comment: You could _ignore_ the full match and focus on the groups you want. All regex engines maintain the full match. It's the default  and only way it knows where to start looking for the next match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex match is always an obligatory output of a regex match operation. Capturing groups are optional, they may be absent. If you define capturing groups to get parts of string in specific context just use those `Submatches`:

```
Dim re As regExp
Dim testString As String, colMatch As MatchCollection, objMatch As Match

testString = "==Index Plate" & vbCrLf & "20137-001.zoe" & vbCrLf & "===Digi Erox" & vbCrLf & "20137-001A.zoe"
Set re = New regExp
With re
  .Pattern = "===(.+)[\r\n](.+)"
  .Global = True
End With

Set colMatch = re.Execute(testString)
For Each objMatch In colMatch
  Debug.Print objMatch.SubMatches(0)  ' <- Print Group 1 value only
  Debug.Print objMatch.SubMatches(1)  ' <- Print Group 2 value only
Next
```

Output:

[image]

NOTE: the `.` matches a CR, so you may want to use `.Pattern = "===([^\r\n]+)[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)"`.